# How to get the values of dynamically created Edit Text values in a Recycler View?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am creating Editext in a recycler view as item based on response from REST API. I need to get the values for the EditTexts created in the list from my activity page. The EditText are being created in the **Adapter**.

How do I get the EditText values ?

[image: screeenshot]

```
private void populateCheckBoxWithText(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    int ctr = 1;
    for (final String optionAns : arrayList.get(position).getOptionList()) {
        Random rand = new Random();

        CheckBox cBoxOption = new CheckBox(activity);
        cBoxOption.setId(ctr);
        cBoxOption.setTag(ctr);
        cBoxOption.setText(optionAns);

        editext_miltiple = new Custom_EditText_Regular(activity);
        editext_miltiple.setId(ctr);
        editext_miltiple.setTag(ctr);
        editext_miltiple.setTextSize(12);
        if (ctr != 1) {
            cBoxOption.setLayoutParams(applyDesignParams(5, 1, 1, 1, 1));
            editext_miltiple.setLayoutParams(applyDesignParams(5, 1, 1, 1, 1));
        } else {
            editext_miltiple.setLayoutParams(applyDesignParams(1, 1, 1, 1, 1));
        }

        editext_miltiple.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        editext_miltiple.setBackground(null);
        editext_miltiple.setHint("Enter response");
        editext_miltiple.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
        editext_miltiple.setPadding((int) AppData.convertDpToPixels(33, activity), (int) AppData.convertDpToPixels(5, activity), 0, 0);

        viewHolder.sub_item.addView(cBoxOption);
        viewHolder.sub_item.addView(editext_miltiple);

        cBoxOption.setOnClickListener(getOnClickDoSomething(cBoxOption, arrayList.get(position).getQuestionID(), null, position, viewHolder));
        //stringBuilder_multi.append(arrayList.get(position).getQuestionID() + ":" + editext_miltiple.getId() + ":");
        //multi_select_txt=arrayList.get(position).getQuestionID() + ":" + editext_miltiple.getId() + ":";
        editext_miltiple.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher(editext_miltiple, position));


        ctr++;

    }
}
```

In the above image link, the Editexts are being created dynamically in a loop. I need to get the values of those Editexts in my activity.

I need to create a pattern like this ==> *CheckBoxValue<>EditTextValue* and send the JSON to server. Eg: **Technical<>edit_text_response**, when user clicks checkbox and types in EditText.

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ArrayList in your class level to save EditTexts you have created in the loop. while creating EditTexts add them into the ArrayList. Like

```
ArrayList<EditText> editTexts = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then in your loop add

```
 editTexts.add(editext_miltiple);
```

Then wherever you want to access the EditText you can access from ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set Tag to each edit text according to its order in creating?

Comment: I have already applied setTag, if you check my given code. But the problem is I dont know how to get its values according to its creation

Comment: Oh sorry , read about Observer pattern , create an interface , implement it in activity , pass it to the adapter in the constructor , and when you receive something call this interface

Answer (score 0):

> first create arraylist type of Edittext then stor each edittext in this arraylist after you want to fetch value from edittext generate loop of arraylist and fetch value